# Issue using virtual KVM java app

Tags: java, console, redirection, kvm-switch, web-application

Receiving this error trying to use console redirection to remotely control a server:

Error: The field  has an invalid value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="https://10.0.0.196/Java" >
     <information>
        <title>JViewer</title>
        <vendor>American Megatrends, Inc.</vendor>
        <description kind="one-line">JViewer Console Redirection Application</description>
        <description kind="tooltip">JViewer Console Redirection Application</description>
        <description kind="short">
            JViewer enables a user to view the video display of managed server via KVM.  
            It also enables the user to redirect his local keyboard, mouse for managing the server remotely.
        </description>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.5+"/>
        <jar href="release/JViewer.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
       <j2se version="1.5+"/>
       <nativelib href="release/Win64.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
        <j2se version="1.5+"/>
        <nativelib href="release/Win32.jar"/>
    </resources>    
    <resources os="Linux" arch="x86">
        <j2se version="1.5+"/>
        <nativelib href="release/Linux_x86.jar"/>
    </resources>    
    <resources os="Linux" arch="i386">
        <j2se version="1.5+"/>
        <nativelib href="release/Linux_x86.jar"/>
    </resources>    
    <application-desc>
        <argument>10.0.0.196</argument>
        <argument>7578</argument>
        <argument><html><head><title>Document Error: Page not found</title></head>
        <body><h2>Access Error: Page not found</h2>
        <p>Could not create token for this session. Max session limit might have reached 
</p></body></html>
```

Yesterday it was working. I would get an error saying it couldn't download the file but if I tried enough times it would go through. Now no matter how many times I try I get an application error every time.

I've tried java 6 and 7 and IE10, 9, 8, and 7.

Answer (score 0):

Probably already resolved, but as I've faced today the same issue I'd post it here for future reference

You need to launch **java control center** and enable the check "keep temporary files on your computer" hence java will be able to save the downloaded file.